# Why doesn't the length of the array change when I add a new property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var arr = ["Hello", "There", 123, 456, {
    show: function (value) {
        alert(value);
    }
}];
arr[4].show(arr[0]);
arr["Hello"] = {
    damn: function () {
        alert("What's happening yo !");
    }
}
arr.Hello.damn();
alert("Arr length is: " + arr.length);
```

Comment: An array should only have numeric keys. Any non-numeric keys won't count for the length.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting ECMA Script 5 Specification of [Array Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4),

> A property name `P` (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P` and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

Since `Hello` is not valid, according to the above definition, it is not considered as an array index but just as an ordinary property.

Quoting MDN's [Relationship between length and numerical properties section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties),

> **When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a valid array index** and that index is outside the current bounds of the array, the engine will update the array's length property accordingly

So, only if the property is a valid array index, the `length` property will be adjusted.

In your case, you have just created a new property `Hello` on the array object.

---

**Note:** Only the numerical properties will be used in all of the `Array`'s prototype functions, like `forEach`, `map`, etc.

For example, the array shown in question, when used with `forEach`,

```
arr.forEach(function(currentItem, index) {
    console.log(currentItem, index);
})
```

would print

```
Hello 0
There 1
123 2
456 3
{ show: [Function] } 4
```

even though the list of keys shows `Hello`.

```
console.log(Object.keys(arr));
// [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'Hello' ]
```

It is because, `Array` is derived from `Object`,

```
console.log(arr instanceof Object);
// true
```

and `Hello` is a valid key of the array object, but just not a valid array index. So, when you treat the array as an Object, `Hello` will be included in the keys, but the array specific functions will include only the numerical properties.

Comment: yes! length doesn't increase if value is saved as "associative array" style.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `length` is only updated when a new *numeric* property is added to the array [as required by the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1):

> The length property of this Array object is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable property whose name is an array index.

And an array index [is specified to be](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4):

> A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 232−1.

However, arrays are also objects - so you can add non-array-index properties to an array, just like you can add properties to any other JavaScript object (which is why your example doesn't throw either).

Answer (score 1):

javascript length is calculated as 1+(highest numeric index element). so when you add `arr['Hello']`, you are only adding a string index which is not taken into account when calculating the array length.

This is the actual definition of the array length property as described in [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4):

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>. The value of the length property is
>   numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an
>   array index; whenever a property of an Array object is created or
>   changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this
>   invariant. Specifically, whenever a property is added whose name is an
>   array index, the length property is changed, if necessary, to be one
>   more than the numeric value of that array index; and whenever the
>   length property is changed, every property whose name is an array
>   index whose value is not smaller than the new length is automatically
>   deleted. This constraint applies only to own properties of an Array
>   object and is unaffected by length or array index properties that may
>   be inherited from its prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

> arr["Hello"]=...

you are creating a new Object associated with the `arr` Array object, which does not affect the length of `arr`.

You can achieve the same effect by writing:

> arr.Hello=...

Comment: No. You can not do it. Result would be same arr.length is 0.