# How to push new elements to an array with undefined index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create array once and then just push values to it with any index , but i get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error

I have following scenario

```
var neg = [];
```

I want to use push randomly with any index

```
neg[0].push([1,2]);
```

or

```
neg[22].push([1,2]);
```

right now I want to define manually like  `neg[0] = [];` , Is there any one way where i can just push to any index i want ?

Comment: You would need to set it before you can push to it

Comment: `neg[0]` is not an array, so your trying to effectively push something onto an undefined value

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235599/array-length-and-undefined-indexes

Comment: Does `neg` have a fixed size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index (JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript)

Comment: `push` is an `Array.prototype` method. You can not use it on non Array values such as `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do exactly what you want.

```js
var arr = [];

(arr[0]=[]).push([1,2]);

console.log(arr)
```

---

Also it's safer to check if an array already exists at this index, otherwise it will be replaced with an empty array – the above code will replace the array with an empty one if it already exists.

```
// creates an array at index 0 only if there's no array at this index.
// pushes an array of [1, 2] to the existing array at 0 index
// or the newly created empty one.
(arr[0] || (arr[0] = [])).push([1, 2]);;
```

```js
var arr = [];

arr[0] = [1];

(arr[0]||(arr[0]=[])).push(2,3);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to set it to an empty array before you can push it.

```
neg[0] = neg[0] || []
neg[0].push([1,2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will add elements to the end of an array. For example:

```
var neg = [];
neg.push(3); //this will add the number 3 to the end of your array
```

The problem here is your trying to add a value to an undefined element:

```
var neg = [];
neg[0].push([1,2]); // <-- neg[0] is not defined at this moment, and you're treating it as an array object.
```

If you define your elements as an array, you will not get such an error:

```
var neg = [];
neg[0] = [];
neg[22] = [];

neg[0].push([1,2]);
neg[22].push([1,2]);
```

Alternatively (and **this is probably what you're probably looking for**), you can set the value for any element of your array with the desired index:

```
var neg = [];

neg[0] = [1,2];
neg[22] = [1,2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how large the array will be if you know ahead of time, for example `var neg = new Array(40);` will create a new array with 40 undefined elements.

Once that is created, you can change the value at any index as long as `0 <= index <= 39`.

Comment: well, unlike in other languages, in JavaScript you can define an array of an undefined length (```var myArray=[]```). Also, note that push will add elements to the end of the array (even beyond it's initial length) and returns the new length of the array --example here: https://jsbin.com/nuriqiqixa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `var neg = [40]` creates an array with one item with the value `40` not an array with `40` items.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array.splice(your_index, 0, your_element);` to push an element into an array at the given index.